# Proper way to get the remote audio levels of a media stream in order to display audio levels visually?

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc, microphone, getusermedia

Looking to do something very similar to the post below, but in the reverse direction, displaying the voice activity level of the inbound media stream from my remote party using webrtc. I was thinking it would be easy by just modifying code to flip it around or run it on the other media stream, but i have had no luck. Anyone doing this now or have any ideas?

[Microphone activity level of WebRTC MediaStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724414/microphone-activity-level-of-webrtc-mediastream)

Comment: Show the code you have tried. Also, make sure to use `createScriptProcessor` instead of `createJavaScriptNode`. Take a look at [this link](https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter) which is an example of a volume meter. Without more code of what you have tried and a specific question it's hard to give an exact answer.

Comment: @chRyNaN I was using createJavaScriptNode, ill play with createScriptProcessor and then post some code in a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, JavaScriptNode is deprecated and replaced by ScriptProcessorNode which is more recently deprecated and would soon be replaced by AudioWorkers (which have not been implemented in most browsers yet).

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be related to a Chrome Bug. Its documented and acknowledged by the chrome team, but doesn't have a short term fix planed based on the most recent comments.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=121673&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=121673

more info on these related links...

[visualize mediastream which is coming from a remote peer connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950937/visualize-mediastream-which-is-coming-from-a-remote-peer-connection)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sip_js/QE3EwXRi-5c

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best method to do this in a cross browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) way, is to get the audio levels of the stream *locally* and transmit them to the peer parallel to the stream, over an RTCDataChannel.  This is the method used by [SimpleWebRTC](https://simplewebrtc.com/demo.html) and at least a couple other apps.

SimpleWebRTC uses a helper library called [hark](https://github.com/otalk/hark) that you can use standalone, to have volume events emitted for the stream. Then, you just have to send them over the data channel to the other peer, and have the peer display the volume according to those events. It's not the ideal solution, but it's a pretty good one.

There's more examples [here](https://simplewebrtc.com/notsosimple.html#audiolevels) regarding the use of hark in SimpleWebRTC. Psuedocode, since detailed examples are elsewhere:

1. Get the stream
2. Set up an audio monitor on the stream
3. create a peer connection for the stream (or attach to incoming)
4. Open a data channel (or get existing) for volume events
5. on audio monitor volume events, emit the event on the data channel
6. monitor the data channel for audio events, and use them to show peer volume

So, very pseudo:

```
getUserMedia(constraints, function (stream) {
   audioMonitor = new Hark(stream);
   connection = new PeerConnection(stream);
   dataChannel = connection.createDataChannel('hark');
   audioMonitor.on('volumeChange', function(volume) {
       dataChannel.send('volume', volume);
   });
   dataChannel.onMessage(function(label, data) {
      if (label == 'volume') {
          //use data to set css, etc to show volume level of peer
      }
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Note that after Chrome 71 (Dec 2018) this approach wont always work - AudioContext object will require user gesture to start working so an attempt to calculate volume immediately after page loads, even if you have mic access granted, wont work until user gesture.