# Remote Audio Processing using Web Audio API and Wrtc

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc, web-audio-api

I am trying to process remote audio from a media stream object received from the server. I am getting multiple media stream objects which are passed to `video` element srcObject and then muted.(like a video conference)
Each media stream object is passed to a separate component that has a unique `video` element and attached to it.
I want to process audio for each media stream object separately and process it accordingly to display necessary visuals.
Problem is, suppose there are 5 users in a call and any random user speaks, the analyser works for only the first media stream object (the first one which was added to the call). How can I check that audio is coming from which specific media stream ? and also why is analyser working for a single media stream ?
The code to analyse audio from media stream object is mentioned here as follows

```
const context = new AudioContext();
const track = context.createMediaStreamSource(this.mediaStreamObj);
const gainNode = context.createGain();
const analyzer = context.createAnalyser();
track.connect(gainNode);
track.connect(analyzer);
gainNode.gain.value = 0;
track.connect(context.destination);
const bufferLength = analyzer.frequencyBinCount;
console.log(bufferLength);
const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
```

The dataArray is used further to get average value for audio level and apply necessary css.
I found a source where it is mentioned that it's a chrome bug, check this link - [Proper way to get the remote audio levels of a media stream in order to display audio levels visually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082362/proper-way-to-get-the-remote-audio-levels-of-a-media-stream-in-order-to-display)
There are multiple sources mentioning the steps for local audio, but I can't find any related to remote audio. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to show a bit more of your code, like how you are analyzing the 5 usrers streams.

Comment: The media stream objects are received in the form of array of objects in the parent. Each object is then passed to the child component and attached to the `video` tag present there. In each of the child component, I am trying to analyse their respective mediastream object by using the snippet(Web Audio API) mentioned in my question.
The process involves , creating source node -> passing media stream object to source node -> creating analyser node -> connecting source to destination.

Comment: It is working fine for just a single media stream i.e only the first one. When a new media Stream object is passed in the same way as above, the analyser gives the audio signal levels just for the first media stream object leaving the rest of the objects.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.  I'll post what I think is the problem in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I think the problem is that a `MediaStreamSourceNode` only has one track, even if the stream has many.  The track used is the "first", which is kind of unspecified.

What you can do is use many `MediaStreamTrackAudioSourceNode`s to get access to each track.  Then add an analyser for each these so you can measure what's happening.

(Note: Chrome hasn't implemented this yet.  See https://crbug.com/679813)

Comment: So, according to you, the source node is working on only single source ? How does it differ from "createMediaStreamTrackSource()" ? It's implementation will be in the same way as mentioned in snippet in the question ?

Comment: From your comments, it seems as if `this.mediaStreamObj` is a video with many audio tracks.  If so, then `createMediaStreamTrackSource` will allow you pick exactly the audio track you want and uses it.  `createMediaStreamSource` picks the "first" track.  That's basically the difference between the two.

Comment: No no, actually each media stream object refers to the stream of a single user that consists of 2 tracks (i.e audio and video track of that particular user). Each user has it's own media stream object. So, I get an array of objects from the server where each object refers to an individual users stream.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I can't see what's wrong with your code then.  Perhaps a bit more complete example would help, especially something I can run from, say, jsfiddle, or codepen or whatever.

Comment: I'm sorry i can't present a working demo as I am getting the media stream objects from a remote server.

Comment: Let me try to explain my problem a bit more clearly . The components hierarchy is like this. Parent -> child 1, 2 ....  n. In parent component, mediastream objects are received dynamically from server. i.e no. of mediastream objetcs = no. of children.
Each  mediastream object is passed to a child component. i.e 1 mediastream per child. And finally in each of the child component, the following steps mentioned in the original question are carried out to analyse the audio level for that specific  mediastream .The analyser is giving audio levels  for the first child only .

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to figure out the issue. The analyser node was working fine for all the media Streams . The problem was related to the `id` of the element to which the `CSS` was being applied to. Turns out that id was unique to each child component containing it's own media stream object. But, since the parent component contains all the children, all the elements to which the `css` has to be applied were having same `id`. That's why the styles were getting applied to a single `id`. So, I made sure that the elements have different id even if they are in different child components and everything is working perfectly now !